# what kind of errors does componentdidcatch catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have wrapped my main component like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Home />
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

just wondering what sort of errors `componentDidCatch` catches? doesn't catch compilation errors, and when I changed this in my child component from

`this.props.users.people.length` to `this.props.users.userslength` it should showed my loading spinner for ages (in my child component there is a ternary operator, not sure if that's affecting it)

just wondering what sort of errors it catches and how i can fake the browser to see it working?

Comment: Error boundaries do not catch errors for:Event handlers,
Asynchronous code,Server side rendering,Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)..more here https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

> Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed. Error boundaries catch errors during rendering, in lifecycle methods, and in constructors of the whole tree below them.

Be sure that you check for errors from child components and that they are caused during rendering and not inside of event handlers or some other asynchronous code. For that code you're still free to use just regular `try/catch`.

Please read carefully the article on the official site about [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed.

So it basically works like the `.catch()` of javascript, only that it catches errors while rendering a component, and that it cannot catch errors within itself.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

Check out their demo.

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010